# ipad - memory warning level 1 ,2 but still having more than enough memory

Tags: ipad, memory, memory-management

My iPad app always gives memory warning level 1 or 2, but **NEVER** crashes. It just display log for warning level 1 or 2, but I **CAN** continue operate on my app without any problem.

Also I have used activity instrument to monitor the memory usage of my app. It costs at most (peak) 40 MB in the life time.

Can someone tell me why? why it still gives warning when it only used up to 40 mb and never crashes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My iPad app always gives memory warning level 1 or 2, but NEVER crashes. It just display log for warning level 1 or 2, but I CAN continue operate on my app without any problem.

That's exactly how the system is supposed to work. The OS sends memory warnings to every process, and everybody frees some unneeded memory. The OS itself can also kill apps that are currently in the background. If enough memory can be freed, nothing needs to be killed. What good would the warnings be when your app would get killed every time anyway?

Comment: But my app costs 40MB at most along its life time, do you think 40MB can lead to warning level 1 or 2?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't on a device that has 256 MB of RAM and tries to keep several apps in memory at once.